# Is there a better way to query value in a dict with the key which is value in another dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have multiple dict.

```
package_sender_map = {'package_1': 'vici'}
sender_level_map = {'vici': 'level_3', 'Jone': 'level_1'}
level_ability_map = {'level_1': '30', 'level_2': '50', 'level_3': '100'}
```

Now I want to get a package's sender's ability. The only way I find out is :

```
level_ability_map.get(sender_level_map.get(package_sender_map.get('package_1')))
```

It looks too long and hard to understand.
Is there a simple and clear way to make relationship with multiple dicts?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. Are you worried about errors due to non-existent keys?

Comment: I have update my question. sorry for my terrible describe.

Comment: Do any of the answers below address your question? You could accept the most helpful one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a stack of your dicts by putting them into a list (or tuple), and then loop over the stack. Like this:

```
package_sender_map = {'package_1': 'vici'}
sender_level_map = {'vici': 'level_3', 'Jone': 'level_1'}
level_ability_map = {'level_1': '30', 'level_2': '50', 'level_3': '100'}

dict_stack = [package_sender_map, sender_level_map, level_ability_map]
v = 'package_1'
for d in dict_stack:
    v = d[v]
print(v)
```

**output**

```
100
```